# Different git merge between eclipse and intellij

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I'v tried to merge a hotfix of my current deployed release branch into my develope branch. 
Intellij found only the changes that were in the hotfix.
eclipse on the other hand found additionally some changes between the release and the develope and put them on the unstaged files.

Why is there a difference between the 2 IDEs? Do they use different git merge or diff? Do they choose different common ancestors?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your `git status` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IDEs don't have anything to do with GIT internal commands.

I think it was a mistake from your own side. I suppose you have two local repos for two IDEs, right?

May be you accidentally merged with different branch.

You said eclipse put some files to upstaged change, may be there's a conflict to that merge. Resolve it.

Comment: Hi thanks. If there was a conflict i would expect to see it in both IDEs.

Comment: Sorry? may be you forgot push any commits in 'eclipse IDE repo' to master and rebase it with that hotfix branch? what does git status show?